# Form opening after stopEditing pyqgs Qgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I made a form that binds some fields on a shp in Qgis (works fine), and after stop editing event the form appears again..
Do you have any ideas?
Made so far:

```
## action 
self.editingObject = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/Count/icons/pen.png"), "&Editing object", self.iface.mainWindow(), toolTip ='<b>Editing object</b>\n Editing object',)
self.editingObject.triggered.connect(self.editing)

def editing(self):

    if not iface.activeLayer():
        QMessageBox.about(None, 'Atention', 'No layer selected')

    self.layer_activ = iface.activeLayer()
    LayerSource = self.layer_activ.source()
    sufix = 'judete_ro.shp'
    if LayerSource.endswith(sufix) :

         self.iface.activeLayer().startEditing ()

         QMessageBox.about(None, 'Info', 'Editing started on layer' + str(iface.activeLayer().name()))

         self.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()

     if self.editingObject.triggered:
         self.layer_activ.featureAdded.connect(self.select_id)
def select_id(self, Fid):
       self.iface.activeLayer().setSelectedFeatures([Fid])
       self.editfrm = editForm()
       self.editfrm.show()
class editForm(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
       QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
       self.ui = Ui_EditForm()
       self.ui.setupUi(self)
       self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)

    def accept(self):

      for i in iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures():

         fid = int(i.id())
         provider = iface.activeLayer().dataProvider()
         name = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("NAME")
         siruta = iface.activeLayer().fieldNameIndex("SIRUTA")
         textNAME = self.ui.NAME.text()
         textSIRUTA = self.ui.SIRUTA.text()
         attr = {name: textNAME, siruta: textSIRUTA}
         iface.activeLayer().changeAttributeValue(fid,name,textNAME)
         iface.activeLayer().changeAttributeValue(fid,siruta,textSIRUTA)
         iface.activeLayer().setSelectedFeatures([])
      self.close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works, but you could try to assign a parent widget to your edit form. I once had similar issues with a window that popped up several times. As far as I remember I solved that by assigning a parent to it.

Comment: The parent  of the class  editForm is not QtGui.QDialog?

Comment: Not sure but is your `self.close()` meant to be outside the `def accept(self):`?

Comment: No, self.close() is in inside the def accept(self) method.

Comment: The problem is that after toggle editing, the method def select_id(self, Fid), is called again and the form appears...

Comment: QtGui.QDialog is the superior class of the editForm, not the parent. As the editForm object is a subclass of a QDialog you can provide it with a parent widget (see the PyQt class reference: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html).

Comment: Update: the form appears also at save layer edit, i think the problem it is related to the featureAdded event...